# Bitmap loading: java.lang.OutofMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I am using Android [ScrollViewGallery](https://github.com/VEINHORN/ScrollGalleryView) to display images that I have taken with the default system camera.

It works fine on my Nexus 5 with Android 6.0. 
It also works fine on a virtual Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 4.3
and a virtual Sony Xperia Z with Android 4.3.

But it does not work on A OnePlus One with Android 4.4
and on a Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

I get the issue:

> java.lang.OutofMemoryError: Java heap space

I do not understand why it works on some devices and on others it does not.

My Code to load the bitmaps:

```
public class ImagesActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static final String PUTEXTRA_IDENTIFIER_ANLAGE = "selectedAnlage";
    static final String PUTEXTRA_IDENTIFIER_MASCHINE = "selectedMaschine";
    public int selectedAnlage;
    public int selectedMaschine;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ScrollGalleryView mScrollGalleryView;
    private List<Image> imagesList;

    private File mediaStorageDir;

    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "SMSImageDokumentation";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_images);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null) {
                selectedAnlage = 0;
            } else {
                selectedAnlage = extras.getInt(PUTEXTRA_IDENTIFIER_ANLAGE);
            }
        } else {
            selectedAnlage= (int) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(PUTEXTRA_IDENTIFIER_ANLAGE);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null) {
                selectedMaschine = 0;
            } else {
                selectedMaschine = extras.getInt(PUTEXTRA_IDENTIFIER_MASCHINE);
            }
        } else {
            selectedMaschine= (int) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(PUTEXTRA_IDENTIFIER_MASCHINE);
        }


        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        imagesList = db.getImagesForKEyMaschineAndAnlage(selectedAnlage, selectedMaschine);

        mScrollGalleryView = (ScrollGalleryView)findViewById(R.id.images_scroll_gallery_view);
        mScrollGalleryView
                .setThumbnailSize(100)
                .setZoom(true)
                .setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager());

        for(int i = 0; i <= imagesList.size() -1; i++)
        {
            try {
                mScrollGalleryView.addImage(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(imagesList.get(i).get_fileName())));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Fehler beim Laden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably this OutofMemoryError exception occurs when you are trying to set a image which is heavy. I am not sure about this, but I am saying it, as once I had got the same issue. I just reduced the dimension of my image and it worked. Another thing you can do is add android:largeHeap="true" inside application tag of your manifest file.